# Create a link in backend to a frontend page

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I would link to create a link to a frontend page inside a backend module.
Using:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="40" >Link</f:link.page>
```

Doesn't work. It generates a link to the current backend module.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very long story but the gist is: it is not possible to create FE links in BE/CLI context without a lot of workarounds and dummy objects/values.

If possible you should use solutions like [pagepath](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pagepath/) which generate URLs for an eID script which performs the actual URL generation on demand.

Answer (score 13):

Since TYPO3 v9 you can use the following lines of code:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteFinder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\Entity\Site;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\PageRouter;

$siteFinder  = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class);
$site = $siteFinder->getSiteByPageId($pageId);
$router = $site->getRouter();
$frontendUrl = (string) $router->generateUri($pageId);
```

Thanks to Benni Mack @ TYPO3Camp Mitteldeutschland

Comment: For additional access to the typoscript configuration you might use this way using TemplateService and PageRepository: https://www.typo3tiger.de/blog/post/typo3-frontend-links-im-cli-context.html